# Chart Labels displays correctly in Visual Studio Preview but shows incorrectly in Report Manager after deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have built a SSRS report which contains a chart and a tablix. The chart labels (Male and Female) is displayed correctly in the Visual Studio Preview but in the Report Manager it displays as Female and Female.

These are the following things which we have tried to fix it:

1. Deleted and redeployed the report
2. Restarted the Report Server
3. Checked the report caching. There is no cache for this report.

We use SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2010.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,

AJ

Comment: What browser are you running Report Manager in? I have had varied results in the past using anything other then IE.

Comment: We always use IE for checking reports in Report Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I would check Data Source definitions, comparing those in Visual Studio with those for the deployed report.  You may be looking at a different database.